# How to find the rise and fall of projections on a external contour in a binary image in Python?

Tags: opencv, scikit-learn

I have a binary image and I am trying to eliminate the projections on it.

I have been able to do the background removal as you can see in Figure 2.

See the black stem in the first figure? I want to remove that, so that my final image looks like the one in figure 3. Any insights for this problem would be appreciated. Please find [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsCGF.png) on imgur, as I am not permitted to post images in my questions yet.

Thanks.

Comment: apply morphological operators

Comment: I have done that, and didn't find it to be good enough for all the images. The original part of the fruit does not come back. There are aberrations in the boundary. I am looking for something more robust. Thanks, though.

Comment: erode + dilate = opening. that should work well enough. use a structuring element that is circular. I've seen "tricks" that use binary operations on different morphology operations.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.